# Make <a> link clickable through the whole <li>

Tags: html, css, html-lists, nav

Please take a look at this:

[image: website menu]

This is my html:

```
    <nav id="mainNav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="projects.html">Our Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="team.html">Our Team</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

And my css:

```
#mainNav ul li {
    padding-left: 10px;
}

#mainNav ul li:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

The links are activated only when I place the cursor above the text's link and click. I would like to able to click anywhere inside the darker "li"'s background and activate the corresponding link. How is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may try this ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/XjyaU/))

```
#mainNav ul li a {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is only possible to click on the **link(text)** because the `<a>` has the height and width of the font, **not** from the `<li>`. If you want to be able to click on the full `<li>` you can use something like this. 
Set the `<a>` around the `<li>`.

**Example:**

```
<a href="index.html"><li>Home</li></a>
```

**Updated with a demo:**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3g978/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can try it like this:

```
<li onclick="location.href='index.html'">Home</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the  tags to the outside of the li tags.

- Alex